# Vue how to detect form input changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my `vue`-app I have a form, which should detect each change. I tried to use `@change` and also with a watcher, but with no luck...

```
form: {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  email: "",
},
changed: false
```

then in my template:

```
<form @change="hasChanged">
```

Then my watcher and method:

```
watch: {
    form: {
        handler: function(v) {
            return this.hasChanged();
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
methods: {
  hasChanged(){
    this.changed = true
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work.... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should put it on an elment that has an change event like an input

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Form element does not have a change listener. Consider binding each input instead with the onChanged event instead.

From what I am seeing it seems like you want to know if the form has been edited. In that case you can try this

```js
<template>
    <form>
        <input v-model="form.first_name"/>
        <input v-model="form.last_name"/>
        <input v-model="form.email"/>
    </form> 
</template>

<script>
    const defaultForm = {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        email: '',
    }  
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
            // form: defaultForm
            // edit
            form: {...defaultForm}
        }
      },
      computed: {
        hasChanged () {
          return Object.keys(this.form).some(field => this.form[field] !== defaultForm[field])
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm this does not work, the computed value always returns false

Answer (score 3):

You can use the watch from vuejs, a very simple trick.

```
watch: {
   'form': {
        handler: function(v) {
         return this.enableFormSubmission();
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Babacar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63706689/7499069) the `hasChanged` always return false as the `form` and `defaultForm` refer to the same object. The form should be a copy before rendering. We can use a shallow copy for the normal case and the nested object, we need to use the deep copy.

```
<template>
    <form>
        <input v-model="form.first_name"/>
        <input v-model="form.last_name"/>
        <input v-model="form.email"/>
    </form> 
</template>

<script>
    const defaultForm = {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        email: '',
    }  
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
            form: {...defaultForm } // copy here
        }
      },
      computed: {
        hasChanged () {
          return Object.keys(this.form).some(field => this.form[field] !== defaultForm[field])
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer @Babacar gave is a long process,
@ST80, yes the change event works

Here is how to use it,

**No need to use a watcher with the form**

Add the event to your form tag

```
<form @change="formUpdated">
```

then add the function

```
    formUpdated (): void {
  this.formNotUpdated = false
}
```

This will work for differntly depending on the input feild type, for example the text input chnage will fire when you click out of the input or
you can use a console.log() to test if it logs something when you change a input..Im guessing your use case is for a profile page where you want to disable a button until a form is updated.

check the documentation here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event